# Ubuntu 14.04 upgrade php or mysql from ppa:ondrej fails after April 2019

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, php7

I have a project in a VM with OS Ubuntu 14 LTS, php5.5 and mysql-server-5.5.

At the end of March I have cloned the Virtual Machine and successfully upgraded both of them  from (ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.7) and (ppa:ondrej/php), and 
I kept the commands in a txt.

Today (30 July) I am trying to do the same in the production machine and I have this error:

> E: Unable to locate package php7 Note, selecting
>   'libapache2-mod-php7.0' for regex 'php7.0' 0 upgraded, 0 newly
>   installed, 0 to remove and 255 not upgraded.
>
> Package mysql-server-5.7 is not available, but is referred to by
>   another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been
>   obsoleted, or is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'mysql-server-5.7' has no installation candidate

I have try many ways to work around the issue with no results.

 Can anyone knows what is the problem with ppa:ondrej ??

The Upgrade to Ubuntu 16 is tested and out of the question..

Answer (score 3):

This [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php) has been discontinued, because the base OS is out of (standard) support.

> Only Supported Versions of PHP (http://php.net/supported-versions.php) for Supported Ubuntu Releases (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) are provided. Don't ask for end-of-life PHP versions or Ubuntu release, they won't be provided.

Since Ubuntu only provides **paid** support for a select number of server packages, an LTS release after the end of Standard Support is effectively EOL for most people. If you still need this, you can pay for the support and use the basic PHP 5.5(?) that are in this support offering.